How to cleanly inject a namespace module's UI into a main app's UI, using R Shiny?
I have two R Shiny example files that use sidebarPanel() and mainPanel(). One file, shown below, is called “Main App”, and the other, also shown below, is called “Mod1”. I would like to make the Mod1 a namespace module used by Main App to add to its respective sidebarPanel() and its mainPanel(). I would like to do this while maintaining the sidebarPanel() and mainPanel() of Mod1 so I can test and build that module separately from the Main App. Note for sake of simplicity the 2 examples are drafted where there is no data sharing between them although that will come later if I can figure out this first step.
Is this possible, and if so, how can this be done? Again, where the UI of Mod1 is embedded in the UI of Main App.
I figure I could build the module without sidebarPanel() and mainPanel(), using tagList() instead, but I need to be able to separately run and test the Mod1 module.
Here is Main App:
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    h4(strong("Main App")),
    h5(strong("Sidebar panel shell:"))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h4(strong("Main App")),
    h5(strong(textOutput("sendMssg1")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$sendMssg1 <- renderText("Main panel shell:")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

What I would like to use as Mod1:
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    h4(strong("Mod1")),
    h5(strong("Base value:")),
    sliderInput("svc", "", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h4(strong("Mod1")),
    textOutput("sendMssg2"),
    br(),
    textOutput("result1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$sendMssg2 <- renderText(paste("You input the base value of: ",input$svc))
  
  output$result1 <- renderText({
    paste("Mod 1 Result = base + 10:", input$svc + 10)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

This example shows how I usually structure my modules, where there is data sharing:
library(shiny)

mod1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  textOutput(ns("result1"))
}

mod1_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      session$userData$mod1(session$userData$shared() + 10)
    })
    output$result1 <- renderText({
      paste("Mod 1 Result = base + 10:", session$userData$mod1())
    })
  })
}

mod2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  textOutput(ns("result2"))
}

mod2_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$result2 <- renderText({
      paste("Mod 2 Result = Mod 1 Result * 2:", session$userData$mod1() * 2)
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    h5(strong("Base value:")),
    sliderInput("svc", "", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0),
    mod1_ui("mod1"),
    mod2_ui("mod2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  session$userData$shared <- reactiveVal(0)
  session$userData$mod1 <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$svc, {
    session$userData$shared(input$svc)
  })
  
  mod1_server("mod1")
  mod2_server("mod2")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Using my MS Paint skills, the merged UI would look like this:


Is it possible that your app will ever run with NO instances of Mod1?  Is it possible that your app could run with multiple instances of Mod1?  If there will ever obnly be exactly one instance of Mod1. I think the simples solution will be to write a helper function that injects the necessary widgets into the sidebar.  Otherwise, more creative solutions will probably be requyired, and we don't have the details to know which mught be best.

By the way, your code under "Here is mod1" does not define a module and your code under " ... data sharing" appears to use an outdated syntax.  Consider using session$userData for inter-module communication.

It is possible that the app would run with no instances of Mod1. It is possible that the app would run with multiple instances of Mod1. Where I said in OP "Here is Mod1" has been changed to "What I would like to use as Mod1"; I need help in converting that to a module Mod1.  I updated the syntax of my example module code to use session$userData per your suggestion.

I found a quite simple solution.
In your mod1 module, you can create two separate ui objects, one for the sidebar and one for the main module.
mod1.R code:
library(shiny)
    
mod1_UI_input <- function(id, embed = TRUE) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  panel <- tagList(
    h4("Module 1"),
    sliderInput(inputId = ns("slider"), label = NULL, min = 0, max = 10, value = 5)
  )
  
  if (!embed) panel <- panel |> sidebarPanel()
  else panel
  
}

mod1_UI_output <- function(id, embed = TRUE) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  panel <- tagList(
    h4("Module 1"),
    textOutput(outputId = ns("num"))
  )
  
  if (!embed) panel <- panel |> mainPanel()
  else panel

}

mod1_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$num <- renderText(input$slider)
    
  })
}

In your app ui, you just have to call the different module parts in the right place:
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      h2("Main App"),
      mod1_UI_input("a")
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      h2("Main App"),
      mod1_UI_output("a")
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mod1_server("a")
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

By calling all the module functions with the same id (in this case "a"), you ensure the server is connected to all of the ui parts.
Screenshot:
sample app
The optional argument "embed" that you can see in the module UI functions is used to render them as simple ui elements or as sidebarPanel and mainPanel elements. This way, you can test the module separately by doing:
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = mod1_UI_input("a", embed = FALSE),
    mainPanel = mod1_UI_output("a", embed = FALSE)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mod1_server("a")
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


This is a neat solution when only a single instance of mod1 is guaranteed  to exist.  It's a good start. But OP has indicated that their app may have zero or many instances of mod1.  How would you generalise this to handle the other situations OP describes?

@Limey I honestly don't really see the problem with having a varying number of mod1 instances throughout the app, but maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.
If you have a variable number of mod1 instances you can just initialize them with a renderUI + lapply. If you have no mod1 instances, then well... you just don't put it there I guess(?)

Limey I may have rushed my response. The full App has many tabs. It's possible the user never goes to the tab that draws on mod1. For now, mod1 is invoked regardless of which tab the user opens so mod1 always runs, now. But later I will want to change the code so if the user doesn't go to a tab, the code for that tab doesn't run in which case the overall App could be used without drawing on mod1. Further, if by "instance" you mean how many times mod1 is referenced or drawn on in the code, it's only once. I had interpreted "instance" to be how many users are running the same code.
